# Choosing a Bean by Profile and Name

Tags: spring-boot

I have an application where a FakeMailService will be injected if i am not on the Production environment. The configurarion is the following:

```
@Bean
@Profile("prod")
public MailService mailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    return new MailServiceImpl(javaMailSender);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MailService.class)
public MailService fakeMailService() {
    return new FakeMailService();
}
```

Now I need to inject que real MailServiceImpl on some specific situations, not caring about the environment. I supposed that it could be achieved using qualified beans, like so:

```
@Bean
@Profile("prod")
public MailService mailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    return new MailServiceImpl(javaMailSender);
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("realMailService")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MailService.class)
public MailService forceRealMail(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    return new MailServiceImpl(javaMailSender);
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MailService.class)
public MailService fakeMailService() {
    return new FakeMailService();
}
```

And then:

```
class SomeService {
    @Autorwired @Qualifier("realMailService")
    MailService theRealMailService;
}

class OtherService {
    @Autorwired
    MailService fakeMailService;
}
```

But it seems that doing that the real MailService (MailserviceImpl) will be injected all the time, it does not matter if I am using the qualifier or not.

Am I missing something? Is there eny ther way to achieve that?

Comment: spring-boot by default auto wires using type. (i.e the IOC looks for the dependent bean with type in the context. if found it is wired together.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with:

```
@Bean
@Profile("prod")
public MailService mailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    return new MailServiceImpl(javaMailSender);
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("realMailService")
@Profile("!prod")
public MailService realMailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    return new MailServiceImpl(javaMailSender);
}

@Bean
@Primary
@Profile("!prod")
public MailService fakeMailService() {
    return new FakeMailService();
}
```